# How to give path to the file?

Tags: php, excel

Hi I want to save the file in excel format in my local folder. For this I am creating an api which will be scheduled to call at every night and save the data in file every night.

My attempt is :

```
    class SaveExcel
{

    function SaveExcel()
    {
    }

    function saveData()
    {
        $file_result = "";
        $database = new Database(Constants::DBHOST, Constants::DBUSER, Constants::DBPASS, Constants::DBNAME);
        $dbConnection = $database->getDB();

        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

        $DB_TBLName = "location"; //MySQL Table Name
        $filename = "LocationHistory(" . $date . ")";         //File Name

//create MySQL connection
        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("Select * from $DB_TBLName");
        $stmt->execute();

        $columnHeader = '';
        $columnHeader = "loc_id" . "\t" . "user_id" . "\t" . "address" . "\t" . "date_time" . "\t";

        $setData = '';

        while ($rec = $stmt->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $rowData = '';
            foreach ($rec as $value) {
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
                $rowData .= $value;
            }
            $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";
        }

          //  file_put_contents('history/' . $filename, $setData);

       return ucwords($columnHeader)."\n".$setData."\n";

        }
    }
?>
```

By this I am getting the output as :

```
"Loc_id\tUser_id\tAddress\tDate_time\t\n\"118\"\t\"1\"\t\"19.166488899999997\"\t\"72.8510805\"\t\"16, Aarey Rd, Jay Prakash Nagar, Goregaon East, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400063, India\"\t\"2018-03-03 18:05:45\"\n\"119\"\t\"1\"\t\"19.165215999999997\"\t\"72.8509167\"\t\"MU Chambers, Jay Prakash Nagar, Goregaon West, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400063, India\"\t\"2018-03-03 18:22:14\"\n\"120\"\t\"1\"\t\"19.1651942\"\t\"72.85087469999999\"
```

now I want to save this data in excel format in local folder.

How can I do this?

Please help.. Thank you.

EDIT :

This code is working well.. Now I just want to give the path to the file. Now its getting saved under the project directory I want to get it saved in another directory. How Can I?

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$rowCount = 1;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, 'Employee');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, 'Address');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, 'Date Time');

$rowCount++;

while($row = $stmt->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $user_name);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['address']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $row['date_time']);
    $rowCount++;
}


$current_date = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $date);
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$name = '/path/to/folder/xyz.xlsx';
$objWriter->save($user_name.$current_date.'.xlsx');

return 'File Saved';
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are showing here is a TSV (tab-separated values) string, which is readable by Excel, but it's not a full Excel spreadsheet (e.g. you can't have colors etc.). This is good enough for many applications, and it can also be read by any app that reads TSVs (from Notepad++ to LibreOffice), which is an advantage.

However, if you want to create actual Excel files, it's much more difficult. There are libraries out there that do it, like this open-source one: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: Someone asked a similar question here, with one of the related libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897666/ziparchiveclose-failure-to-create-temporary-file-permission-denied-nginx

Comment: Hi, you should avoid altering question details fundamentally after you have some answers, it would really confuse anyone viewing this page later. If you have an unrelated question you can ask another one. In any case, I think what you want now is to modify the path in the `save` function, i.e. you need to put the entire path you want, not just the file name.

Comment: I tried to add path like this :   $objWriter->save("/history/$user_name."(".$date.")".'.xlsx');  but this dosent work @Ynhockey

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? /history looks like a strange place to store things, and it's likely your app doesn't have permissions to write to that folder anyway. Try using a relative path, or get your absolute path first and then append to it (this is how it's done in most large projects). If it doesn't work please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add header of type excel on your code.

```
$filename = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

header("Content-Type: application/xls");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
```

`application/xls` work on < `excel 2007`. so if get error on excel, you can change that to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

in other way, [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) is a good plugin to customize your output excel

hope this help you.

Comment: this statements, should be in your function
`header("Content-Type: application/xls");`
`header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");`

Comment: why? becacuse you have to set type content that you want to download. and your code will not download the file. and why again? the browser didnt know what file will be downloaded. so need to add 

`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xlsx"); `
its like on my first comment, put it on your function before `$objWriter->save($filename.'.xlsx');`

and i think, you should change this `$objWriter->save($filename.'.xlsx');` to ` $objWriter->save('php://output');`.
sorry for my bad language.

Comment: try changing the `$objWriter->save()` code to the following:

`$objWriter->save(str_replace(__FILE__,'folder_path/'.$user_name.$current_date.'.xlsx',__FILE__));`

You may change the `folder_path` depending on what you need