# PHPWord not saving file in /tmp directory

Tags: php, phpword

I am trying to run PHPWord's basic example in [here](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html) on my Mac.

I am using XAMPP as app server.

I only changed the `require_once` part and added sys_get_temp_dir() in front of the file name because of the "`ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied`" error as same as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897666/ziparchiveclose-failure-to-create-temporary-file-permission-denied-nginx) question.

My `index.php` file is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

/* Note: any element you append to a document must reside inside of a Section. */

// Adding an empty Section to the document...
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
// Adding Text element to the Section having font styled by default...
$section->addText(
    '"Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. '
        . 'The important thing is not to stop questioning." '
        . '(Albert Einstein)'
);

/*
 * Note: it's possible to customize font style of the Text element you add in three ways:
 * - inline;
 * - using named font style (new font style object will be implicitly created);
 * - using explicitly created font style object.
 */

// Adding Text element with font customized inline...
$section->addText(
    '"Great achievement is usually born of great sacrifice, '
        . 'and is never the result of selfishness." '
        . '(Napoleon Hill)',
    array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10)
);

// Adding Text element with font customized using named font style...
$fontStyleName = 'oneUserDefinedStyle';
$phpWord->addFontStyle(
    $fontStyleName,
    array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10, 'color' => '1B2232', 'bold' => true)
);
$section->addText(
    '"The greatest accomplishment is not in never falling, '
        . 'but in rising again after you fall." '
        . '(Vince Lombardi)',
    $fontStyleName
);

// Adding Text element with font customized using explicitly created font style object...
$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
$fontStyle->setBold(true);
$fontStyle->setName('Tahoma');
$fontStyle->setSize(13);
$myTextElement = $section->addText('"Believe you can and you\'re halfway there." (Theodor Roosevelt)');
$myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyle);

echo(sys_get_temp_dir() . '/helloWorld.docx');
// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save(sys_get_temp_dir() . '/helloWorld.docx');

/* Note: we skip RTF, because it's not XML-based and requires a different example. */
/* Note: we skip PDF, because "HTML-to-PDF" approach is used to create PDF documents. */
```

However it gives no error and also not created the `helloWorld.docx` file.
What is the reason and how can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Please try changing

```
$objWriter->save(sys_get_temp_dir() . '/helloWorld.docx');
```

to

```
$objWriter->save('./helloWorld.docx');
```

(2) Make sure you have write permission to your current folder.

(3) Run the program and see whether the helloWorld.docx is created in your current folder

Comment: Thanks. I only can succeed when I gave `chmod 777` to htdocs. Are there any other "better" options for that?

Comment: Good to know that you fixed the problem. I think you may also try chmod a+w to htdocs. (give write permissions only). Another way is to create a subfolder say "outdoc" so that you save to ./outdoc/helloWorld.docx and make the outdoc writeable