# How to save a Document on a Specific path in PHP Word

Tags: php, phpword

I have a question about **PHP Word** and **I can't find a way to save my file** in the templateprocessor or anywhere else. The file is always automatically moved to the Temp folder.

Does anyone know in which file I have to change the location in the PHP Word library or how I have to declare the command exactly?

thanks for your help

```
<?php
require_once 'bootstrap.php';

$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/ITP-Warehouse/Test/Documents/test.docx/');

$templateProcessor->setValue('title', 'name');

$pathToSave = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ITP-Warehouse\Test\Documents';
$templateProcessor->saveAs($pathToSave);
$documentName = $templateProcessor->save();
$NewdocumentName = substr($documentName, 0, -3);
$NewdocumentName = $NewdocumentName . "docx";
rename($documentName,$NewdocumentName);
$datei_url = $NewdocumentName;
?>
```

Comment: please look into it https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1388

Comment: yes i already did but that doesn't help me much. Anyway thanks

Comment: look into this    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466230/phpword-not-saving-file-in-tmp-directory

Comment: unfortunately still not working